# Can somebody help me in finding distance using zipcodes and Google APIs

Tags: apex, google

how to feed values from SOQL to the API, that is feed zip code to the API.
And calculate the distance between the two zip code.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is regarding querying zip code from any of the two records in Salesforce to find the distance between them using google api, then below is the code snippet:

```
List<Account> lstAccounts = [SELECT ShippingPostalCode FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Test1' OR Name = 'Test'];

Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
HttpResponse resp;
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setEndpoint('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins='+lstAccounts[0].ShippingPostalCode+'&destinations='+lstAccounts[1].ShippingPostalCode+'&language=en-EN&sensor=false');
resp = http.send(req);
System.debug('------resp-----------'+resp.getBody());
```